# Single Quotes Converting to Special Characters using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, amazon-ses

I am making SES Templates using the AWS CLI and having issues with single quotes converting to special characters when the emails are sent.

This also happens when doing a DynamoDB put item operation using the CLI when a string contains a single quote within it.

I've tried backslashes, wrapping the quote in double quotes then escaping it etc.

aws ses send-bulk-templated-email --cli-input-json file://test.json
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name TABLE --item file://item.json

Item/Test Example (snippets of the json):

test: "SubjectPart":"Happy birthday! Get more involved in managing your healthcare now that you're 18"

item:
"S": "Now that you're 18"

Output:

Happy birthday! Get more involved in managing your healthcare now that youâ€™re 18

and

Now that youâ€™re 18

Expected:

Happy birthday! Get more involved in managing your healthcare now that you're 18

and

Now that you're 18

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're using Linux or Mac, with the bash shell ...

Here is an example of how to escape quote characters when using the awscli:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table mytable \
    --item '{"id":{"S":"1"}, "name":{"S":"Fred'\''s Garage"}}'
```

Here is a second way:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table mytable \
    --item $'{"id":{"S":"1"}, "name":{"S":"Fred\'s Garage"}}'
```

In the latter example, words of the form $'string' are treated specially and allow you to [quote certain characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell).

Answer (score 2):

Welp after many trial and errors this is what worked:

you\u2019re

I have no idea why but it did.  Posting this answer in case others experience this as well.

Example:

"SubjectPart":"Happy birthday! Get more involved in managing your healthcare now that you\u2019re 18"

This will give you the expected output.

Comment: Also character entity HTML reference code worked as well - &#39; will output '

Comment: `&rsquo;` also probably would have worked... but there's an explanation in there somewhere: `youâ€™re` results from improper unicode handling and can be traced back to a logical explanation.  If you take "right single quote" U+2019 and encode it as UTF-8, the bytes are hex 0xE2 0x80 0x99, which are the decimal values 226 128 153, which are the code points for the characters â € ™... so I believe you are, at some point, either double-encoding or treating already-encoded bytes as not-yet-encoded characters, causing them to be re-encoded by the SDK/CLI.  Hard to say exactly where.